# What should be the purpose of the [i386] tag? Is it just another spelling of [x86]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, synonym-removal-request

Currently the [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i386) wiki mentions:

> Intel's first 32-bit processor, the 80386, was labeled i386 on the package.

However, most questions are not about the specific CPU¹. The questions are about the architecture, for which we already have [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86). I think they should be synonyms.

Please support me if you agree: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/synonyms

If there's some point to keep the tag, then probably we should rewrite the wiki to match actual usage.

¹ Looks like there's ony one question that means specifically the i386 CPU -- this one: [Emulating a 386](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5270850/2945027)

Comment: They... should be about the specific CPU... But yeah, I imagine they are not, not with 280 questions to its name.

Comment: @CodyGray, it is possible to check and retag those 280 question, but I don't think the 281st would be about the CPU anyway...

Comment: Maybe if someone want a tag about the CPU, they should go with [tag:80386] which is far less likely to be used for the whole architecture

Comment: It should probably be about 32-bit mode specifically (since for example Linux and GNU tools use "i386" as a target ISA name), as opposed to [x86-16] or [x86-64].  (Or [x86] which is about the x86 ISA and x86 CPUs *in general*, although for asm questions it's usually used instead of x86-64 for questions with 32-bit code, so we don't really need i386 for that.)  Or else could usefully be about the baseline 32-bit ISA without extensions like bswap or cmov?  I don't think it's a good choice for a tag name to actually be about 80386, so lets change the meaning away from being 80386 specifically.

Comment: And BTW, I don't think we need an [80386] tag, just like we don't need a [skylake] or [zen1] tag, or even a [zen] tag.  [intel][x86] with 386 (preferably 80386) in the text is specific enough for people to find questions about actual 80386SX or DX features or performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Maybe i386 for 32-bit x86 is a good choice. Except that this use of i386 name is not common in Windows world: we call it just x86.

Comment: I don't see baseline 32-bit x86 ISA meaning much better from 80386 CPU meaning: the amount of correct use is expected to be very small (it looks unusual to avoid bswap added in 486). And as I can see we don't have tags for a baseline of another ISA

Comment: Do you think the idea of using [i386] for 32-bit x86 is good enough to mention [i386] in [x86] wiki?

Comment: I don't think we really *need* a tag for the 386 baseline for 32-bit mode.  That was just a random idea which on 2nd thought I don't like very much either. It's not relevant for modern usage; the standard baseline for 32-bit mode is ppro (aka i686 in the GCC/Linux world), and these days often with SSE2.  IDK if we need a tag for 32-bit mode specifically, other than [x86].  We already have `[x86] [32-bit]` if we need it, although [32-bit] and [64-bit] are stupid tags for that because they applies equally to [arm] [32-bit], only making sense for stuff like [c] writing 64-bit-clean code.

Comment: I think if we're not going to burninate i386 entirely, it should mean the thing that it means when it shows up in Linux / GCC: 32-bit mode.  e.g. i386-linux-gnu as the GCC triple.  But good question about mentioning in the x86 tag wiki, maybe no. (The fact that Windows narrowed x86 to mean specifically 32-bit mode just creates confusion when people want to talk about x86 in general as opposed to ARM or MIPS, e.g. x86 has cheap unaligned access.  Questions about Intel or AMD [cpu-architecture] that aren't specific to 64-bit-mode CPU features should be tagged [x86], but that doesn't mean 32-bit)

Comment: My only real concern for synonyms is that [i386] seem to have a lot of Q&A for _obtaining/using builds of something for x86_, which are not really ISA Q&A. Does [x86] have much less of this due to how questions are asked initially, or by ongoing retagging?

Comment: IA-32 is currently a synonym for x86, it could have been better as a tag specific to 32-bit

Comment: We don't do "polls" here. Post the answer with the approach you think is best, and offer a defense in favor of it. If someone disagrees, they can post an answer presenting and defending their alternative.

Comment: @CodyGray: and what is the difference to a poll then?

Comment: People defend their own answers, rather than having a single person post a bunch of answers that they don't agree with, just to create a poll. @ThomasWeller

Comment: Wrote an answer that reflect my current vision.

Comment: As a point of interest, that one i386 question is off-topic...

Answer (score 4):

After some discussion in comments here I accept that [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i386) could serve as 32-bit flavor of x86 architecture. Though this is not very intuitive for Windows folks, where this naming is not used.

We may need a tag for 32-bit version of x86 ISA. We do have [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) (with useful [amd64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd64) synonym), and [x86-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-16).

[ia-32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ia-32) may serve as a better tag for 32-bit version of x86 ISA, as it explicitly contains "32", and the x64 version was never called ia-32 or "ia-something".

So I'm proposing the following plan:

- unsynonimize [ia-32] from [x86]
- make [ia-32] tag about 32-bit x86
- make [ia32] tag synonym of [ia-32], not [x86]
- after the above is done, consider making [i386] synonym of [ia-32]
- before the above is done, change [i386] wiki to reflect its current usage